# What is the best way to check the Online status of a computer?

Tags: node.js, rest, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a server and several client devices. All devices are running Ubuntu OS. I have an ExpressJs based Node application in the server. I am trying to track the online status of the client devices.

The NodeJs application in the server is integrated with get/post endpoints and web sockets via SocketIO. The server has a public IP on the internet and the devices does not have public IPs

The client devices also have a small application which can communicate with the server via web sockets and can send API calls.

What is the best way to track the online status of each device? (Considering performance of server application, latency, reliability etc.)

1. By sending api calls from client devices to the server periodically
2. By sending Web Socket messages from clients to the server periodically
3. Using an on demand check by the server to devices via Web Socket calls
4. Any other approach? Please explain

Comment: May not be optimal, but the "surefire" way is for each client to send a "heartbeat", a short, simple signal that just signify "I am still alive and connected" periodically, and for the server to update the online status following the heartbeat (Missed 1 heartbeat? Oh well. 3 in a row? May have a problem. 10? Device is down). It is also really simple to make once you have implemented your communication protocol.

Comment: Thanks. That's the mechanism I am using at the moment(I am using ReST calls). But recently I have experienced some cases where a noticeable time difference is seen between actual online status and online status shown in my server application

Answer (score 1):

If you open a permanent websocket connection to your server in your devices, socket.io provides all what you need.

See the `pingTimeout` and `pingInterval` options [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io).

Example:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.engine.pingInterval = 5000; // considers the connection closed after 5 seconds without a pong response from the client
io.engine.pingTimeout = 3000; // sends a new ping packet after 3 seconds
```

When a client is disconnected because of a ping timeout, "ping timeout" is passed in the disconnect event of the socket:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.on("disconnect", function(socket, e) {
        // e contains "ping timeout"
        // possible other values: "transport close" (connection closed by the client)
        // or "server namespace disconnect" (connection closed by the server)
    });
});
```

It's the same in the client.

See also `reconnection`, `reconnectionAttempts` and so on in the client: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/